# WEB API JSON Result with object name

Tags: ember.js, asp.net-web-api, ember-data, asp.net-web-api2

I am working with Web Api and Ember JS, all worked well until i started using Ember Data, which seems to need the object name included in the json.

How can i add this?

Currently getting :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "maxima",
    "subTitle": null,
    "description": "Maxima de boot",
    "image1": null,
    "image2": null,
    "active": false,
    "skipper": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "beatrix",
    "subTitle": null,
    "description": "Beatrix de boot",
    "image1": null,
    "image2": null,
    "active": false,
    "skipper": null
  }
]
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked with Web API and Ember Data plenty you will find it easier to fix the json client side using a serializer.  Assuming you're finding posts, `this.store.find('post') you would create a custom serializer for it:

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
    payload = {posts: payload};
    return this._super(store, type, payload);
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/623/edit

Read more about it (and other methods) here http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray and here https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Answer (score 1):

Ember data doesn't know how to map that data, your json should look like this instead.

```
{ blogs: [ 
  { "id": 1, "title": "maxima", "subTitle": null, "description": "Maxima de boot", "image1": null, "image2": null, "active": false, "skipper": null },
  { "id": 2, "title": "beatrix", "subTitle": null, "description": "Beatrix de boot", "image1": null, "image2": null, "active": false, "skipper": null } ] 
}
```

Now ember knows that the objects from the server, should be mapped to the blogs model.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your reply! Yes i know, the problem is web api default behaviour outputs the above json without object name, I want to know how to change the output in web api to the correct format.

Comment: You can solve this problem through the solution given by at: http://www.emadibrahim.com/2014/04/09/emberjs-and-asp-net-web-api-and-json-serialization/ However, there is an another problem because this solution would work for GET, for other VERB you will receive null at server side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this and haven't worked with Ember before, but... Instead of returning *an array of "stuff" objects*, can you not modify the code to return *an **object** that internally just contains an array of "stuff" objects*? Then, I expect the default json serializer should take care of this for you.